# Classic ASP Screen Scraping

Tags: asp-classic, web-scraping

I want to scrape a aspx file using a Classic ASP script.
I need to first login and then scrap something from the my account page.

I am able to login, but then I am not able to get the my account page.
The site uses ajax login which returns true or false and then redirects to my account page.

```
Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", strInputURL, False
objXMLHTTP.Send "'username=xxx@xxx.com&pwd=xxxxxx&login=true"
strPageText = objXMLHTTP.responseText
```

It returns login=success as respone.
Now after this I need to access the my account page.
When I do that, it again shows the login page, that means the second time when url is called the login status doesn't stay.

Appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the aspx page requires cookies to somehow identify a user and track their login status. You will probably need to capture the cookie(s) and resubmit them (as headers) on subsequent page requests.

If you are not sure how to send and receive cookies then you will find what you need on this blog post: [ASP: Sustain Remote Cookie Sessions in an ASP/VBScript](http://blog.netnerds.net/2006/04/asp-sustain-remote-cookie-sessions-in-an-asp-script-using-vbscript/).